# Why can't add a primary key?

Tags: postgresql

Create a database for testing:

```
create database sample
```

And enter into it:

```
\c sample
```

Create a table and insert value:

```
sample=# create table sample(title text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 213.818 ms
sample=# insert into sample (title) values('x1');
INSERT 0 1
Time: 6.030 ms
```

Now i want add a primary key on the table:

```
sample=# alter table sample add primary key (id);
ERROR:  column "id" of relation "sample" does not exist
Time: 0.523 ms
```

Why can't add a primary key ? How can?

Comment: `Why can't add a primary key` because that column simply does not exist. Create the column, then create the key for that column.

Comment: `alter table sample add column id integer PRIMARY KEY;`

Answer (score 0):

Create it first:

```
sample=# alter table sample add id serial;
```

Then add attribution `primary`:

```
sample=# alter table sample add primary key (id);
```

Comment: That can be done in one step.